# Passport-local-mongoose serializeUser incorrect type

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local-mongoose

I'm trying to use Passportjs, and mongoose for authentication but I am having a hard time getting the correct type with typescript.

```
Passport.use(UserModel.createStrategy())
Passport.serializeUser(UserModel.serializeUser()) // <---- Error
```

I get the error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(fn: (user: User, done: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(user: PassportLocalModel<User>, cb: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(user: User, done: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'user' and 'user' are incompatible.
        Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'PassportLocalModel<User>': authenticate, serializeUser, deserializeUser, register, and 68 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(fn: (req: IncomingMessage, user: User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(user: PassportLocalModel<User>, cb: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: IncomingMessage, user: User, done: (err: any, id?: unknown) => void) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'user' and 'req' are incompatible.
        Type 'IncomingMessage' is missing the following properties from type 'PassportLocalModel<User>': authenticate, serializeUser, deserializeUser, register, and 53 more.
```

This is what my User class looks like:

```
export interface User extends Document {
  email: String
  password: String
  displayName: String
}

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: String,
    displayName: String,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

UserSchema.plugin(PassportLocalMongoose, {
  usernameField: 'email',
})

export const UserModel = model('User', UserSchema)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE** - [my PR landed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/54932) so this has been fixed in [v6.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/passport-local-mongoose/v/6.1.0) of `@types/passport-local-mongoose`. To get the fix update this dependency to 6.1.0 then extend the `Express.User` class from your own mongo `User`. Because your Mongo `User` is using the same class name as the Express `User` you need to create an alias, as shown below.  Do this before you call `Passport.serializeUser`  and you should be good to go.  You can put the Express.User extension anywhere you want, I added in my `routes/user.ts` as that is the most appropriate place in my codebase.

```
type _User = User;

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User extends _User {
    }
  }
}

Passport.use(UserModel.createStrategy())
Passport.serializeUser(UserModel.serializeUser()) // <---- No Error
```

-- ORIGINAL ANSWER --

I believe this is a bug in @types/passport-local-mongoose which I [reported today](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/54870).  You can fix the bug by adding a cast to any like this.

```
Passport.use(UserModel.createStrategy())
Passport.serializeUser(UserModel.serializeUser() as any) // <---- No Error
```

Comment: Hopefully they fix it, I was just using `//@ts-ignore` but I like this method of casting it as any. Thank you for reporting it.

Comment: I just landed a [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/54932) for this as well.

Comment: Hi @TroySandal, I installed @types/passport-local-mongoose 6.1.5, which should be more recent than your fix, but I'm getting the same error. 

Your original answer works though. My code is very similar to the original user's code, except my interface is named IUser. Any chance you could include a full example? I also tried to follow the code you have in your PR without success.